# Another index.php?p= problem

Tags: url

I can't get rid of that pesky index.php?p= from my urls.

http://mysite.com/index.php?p=about/people

If I manually remove index.php?p= e.g. http://mysite.com/about/people it works, but then goes back to adding the index.php?p= as soon as I navigate away.

I've tried adding 'usePathInfo' => true, and 'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true, to general.php

PathInfo works, http://mysite.com/index.php/testPathInfo = 'success'

When I add garbage to htaccess I get server error, so htaccess works.

And I have another site with a very similar build on the same server that's working fine.

Is there anything else I can look at?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `index.php?p=` isn't actually present in you `siteUrl` config variable?

Comment: I'm using baseUrl with {baseUrl} in Site URL in general settings, and no index.php?p= present.

Comment: Is this a vanilla Apache install?

Comment: It's on a new VPS and I've added the missing extensions to get Craft up and running. For another site on the exact same server I'm not seeing the rogue index.php

Comment: If I avoid using the url link e.g. {{ aboutUs.url }} it gets rid of the index.php. For example, this works: <a href="{{ siteUrl }}about-us/{{ aboutUs.slug }}">{{ aboutUs.title }} and this doesn't: <a href="{{ aboutUs.url }}">{{ aboutUs.title }}</a> . It works by splitting up the url with a slug variable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this on the Craft site: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/why-index.php ?

Comment: yes, I've tried this, I mentioned it in my post.

Comment: This post has NOT been answered. I can only find a temporary fix.

Comment: I have the same issue as described here. Stumped.