# Cannot remove index.php from URLs either

Tags: config, htaccess, index

I am having the same issue as here: [Another index.php?p= problem](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9960/another-index-phpp-problem)

I tried to post this as a comment rather than open another post but I don't have enough reputation...

I have tried all of the suggestions listed and none of them are working. Without index.php I get 404's.

I've tried with the rule applied to the config file it breaks the admin (doesn't load asset files like css - they're still pointing to URLs with index.php) and I still get 404's on the entry URLs.

I also double checked with the hosting company on the apache configurations and the `AllowOverride All` is indeed set.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I did try to add `RewriteBase /` just below `RewriteEngine On` and nothing happened. I also verified the file is actually working by adding invalid stuff in it and getting a server error.

I've tried this in my general.php config file:

```
return array(
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
);
```

And this version:

```
return array(
    '*' => array (
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true
    )
);
```

When I do, it doesn't fix the index.php issue, but it removes index.php from the admin, but breaks the admin because the assets 404 (mentioned above).

Any other suggestions out there?

Thanks!

Comment: What happen if you go to `http://yourdomain.com/index.php/testPathInfo`?

Comment: I get the "success" message, forgot to mention I tried that one too :/ (just checked again to be sure ;) )

Comment: Do you have any `.htaccess` files in folders above Craft's `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I don't, here is a screenshot of the folder structure on the server: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4hsuimzkgfpgqm/Screenshot%202016-09-15%2017.19.15.png?dl=0)

Comment: Hrm... forgive me if this sounds stupid, but you are running Apache?

Comment: np :) it is - Apache/2.4.10

Comment: Hrm... running out of ideas.  If you want to send some CP/FTP credentials to support@craftcms.com, we can take a look at it and update here with any results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the Apache `mod_rewrite` module wasn't installed, so the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block of Craft's default `.htaccess` file was being skipped not allowing `index.php` to be rewritten in the URL.